# How to delay "ngondestroy" hook calling while components destroy?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I want to delay `ngOndestroy` hook calling since I am facing one issue which is i have created angular application, in that I have used animation.

sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iribr7-zorjpc?file=app.component.html

When I press `toggl` button, my components get displayed with animation. When I press that button 2nd time, my component get destroyed before animation.

In my components `ngOndestroy` hooka I have used below:

```js
    ComponentBase.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function () {
        /* istanbul ignore else  */
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && this.element.classList.contains('e-control')) { 
        /* used to delete DOM element to avoid memory leak */
            this.destroy(); 
        /* used to delete template refrences to avoid memory leak */
            this.clearTemplate(null);  ------> used 
        }
    };
```

I have tried `settimeout` method also, while using `setTimout` it works fine while debugging but with out that same issue again

I am expecting any other work around or suggestion to resolve this.....

I tried like below but no luck for me----------

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iribr7-bxvnwg?file=app.component.html

Comment: Wow that looks hacky. Maybe this can help: https://indepth.dev/posts/1366/demystifying-angular-router-what-is-routerscroller-and-why-is-it-useful-2